# bison precedence doesn't work

Tags: bison

This is my flex code

```
%{
 #include "fl.tab.h"
%} 
    %% 
    [0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); 
        return INTEGER; } 
    \n  return 0;   
    [ \t]   ;   
    .   return yytext[0];
    %%
```

And my bison code

```
%{ 
    #include <stdio.h> 
%} 
%token INTEGER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*'
%% 
Statement : expr {printf("%d\n",$1);}
        ;
expr :  expr '+' INTEGER  {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' INTEGER  {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  expr '*' INTEGER  {$$ = $1 * $3;}        
     |  INTEGER {$$ = $1;}
     ;
%% 

int main(void){
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

when i input 4 + 5 * 2 it give the output as 18. But the correct answer should be 14. Where am i getting it wrong ?

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that you have `expr OP INTEGER` for each rule.

The way you have it bison parses it as:

```
expr * 2 -> (4 + 5) * 2
```

It forces precedence to go to the left instead of precedence being determined by your precedence rules.

Precedence only applies when there is more than one way to parse the text, instead of what you have, try

```
expr :  expr '+' expr  {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' expr  {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  expr '*' expr  {$$ = $1 * $3;}        
     |  INTEGER {$$ = $1;}
     ;
```

That way `5 + 4 * 2` can be parsed as either `((5 + 4) * 2)` or `(5 + (4 * 2))`, and bison will consult precedence to determine the correct parse.

Answer (score 2):

You can force precedence using reduction:

```
expr    : sum
        ;

sum     : sum '+' product {$$ = $1 + $3;}
        | product
        ;

product : number '*' product {$$ = $1 * $3;}
        | number
        ;

number  : INTEGER
        ;
```

That way, `product` is reduced before `sum`.

Comment: but  isn't the %left keyword used to make bison resolve precedence issues ? My way it should work don't you think ? I wonder why it doesnt work for me. :(

Comment: No. `%left` indicates associativity. `1 + 2 + 3` is reduced to `(1+2)+3` when it's left associative. For right associativity it would be `1+(2+3)`.

Comment: what happens if i don't define associativity ?

Comment: Good question. I suppose, it defaults to left associativity.

Comment: well i removed all the %left statements and placed %right '*' . Still no luck. What can i do.

Comment: Replacing isn't what you want: `1 - 2 - 3` would actually be `1 - (2 - 3)` for right associativity. That gives a wholly different result. Regarding operator precedence, [consult the bison manual](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_8.html#SEC71) where it says: *The relative precedence of different operators is controlled by the order in which they are declared.*

Comment: well but the problem is in my bison seem to ignore the associativity rules that i set. for both right and left associativity rules i get the same answer. how can i fix that ?

Comment: Honestly, I encountered this problem, too. I came up with the above example to circumvent spontaneous "precedence-ignoring".

Comment: %left '+' '-' is it the same as %left '-' '+' ?

Comment: _The relative precedence of different operators is controlled by the order `of the lines` in which they are declared_. See also "Shift/Reduce Conflicts and Operator Precedence" in "flex & bison
by John R. Levine" where he calls it explicit precedence. I find his advice for when not to use (extra) reduction rules quite valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think all rules have precedence of 'INTEGER' since it is the last terminal

Answer (score -2):

Consider for instance the following grammar:

```
           %nonassoc "="
           %left "+"
           %left "*"
           %precedence "("
           %%
           stmt:
             exp
           | "var" "=" exp
           ;

           exp:
             exp "+" exp
           | exp "*" "num"
           | "(" exp ")"
           | "num"
           ;
```

Bison reports:

```
           warning: useless precedence and associativity for "="
            %nonassoc "="
                      ^^^
           warning: useless associativity for "*", use %precedence
            %left "*"
                  ^^^
           warning: useless precedence for "("
            %precedence "("
                        ^^^
```

One would get the exact same parser with the following directives instead:

```
           %left "+"
           %precedence "*"
```

please try this you will get right answer.....

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Bison-Options.html. See the warnings under the section "precedence". This guy just copy-pasted it.